# How abnormal is Vermont's Democratic lean considering its rurality?

Tags: united-states, voting, population

I am curious about the urban-rural divide. While looking into this, I found Vermont. This state is over 90% white and rural yet somehow generally votes Democratic and even houses an Independent senator who is seen as the founding father of the American progressive movement.

Exhibit A:
[image]
<sub>(Source: [FiveThirtyEight](https://fivethirtyeight.com/features/how-urban-or-rural-is-your-state-and-what-does-that-mean-for-the-2020-election/))</sub>

This does not look at population density directly, but it looks at closeness of residents of a state. As I can see, there is only one other state remotely like it: Maine. Even that one voted Democratic by less than five points. I am not focusing on the racial demographics (white people in urban areas also tend to support Democrats), but I am focusing on the population density angle specifically in the US in the 2016 election. Are there any other places like it outside of New England in America?

Comment: Maybe northwestern Mississippi and the middle of Alabama. But those places don't support Bernie.

Comment: "even houses an Independent senator who is seen as the founding father of the American progressive movement"!?!?   [William Jennings Bryan is not happy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Jennings_Bryan).  And [Robert La Follette](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_M._La_Follette) actually won electoral votes as the [Conference for Progressive Political Action's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conference_for_Progressive_Political_Action) candidate in the 1924 US Presidential election.

Comment: The *modern* founding father.

Comment: I don't think I understand the distinction being made here between "population density" and "closeness of residents". Do you mean that you would like to compare counties or some smaller geographical unit within states?

Comment: I understand what you mean by density and closeness. I want to compare it by counties. And, that closeness thing, I would like to know if there is a similar area where the closeness resembles or is less than Vermont but also resembled its net Democratic voting rate in 2016

Comment: What I said earlier makes sense. Do the Black Belt of AL and maybe MS.

Comment: It's possible that the regional predisposition (NorthEast states tend to be blue) outweighs the traditional philosophy that rural states vote red.

Comment: It is not a traditional philosophy. It is a tendency. That is possible that the lean is about the region and not the density. But what about northern Maine in 2016?

Comment: Related: https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/49527/130

Comment: @BrianZ, "closeness" is a fine-grained measure of how spread-out people are.  Consider a square mile of land with ten people living in ten houses spread around it: it's got a density of ten people per square mile, which is rather low, and nobody's very close to anyone else.  Now, consider a square-mile farm with ten people living in the farmhouse: although the density is the same, the closeness is much higher.

Comment: I'm obliged to point out that 'rural' and 'urban' are conceptual broad strokes. I doubt Vermont would be considered an outlier if we weren't using such an insensitive metric. Rural Vermont has almost nothing in common (sociologically or historically) with rural Kansas or rural Texas; the assumption that they all would vote along the same lines merely because they share low population density is exceedingly suspect.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Pretty abnormal, and certainly the best example of an exception to the traditional wisdom of urban/democrat, rural/republican. Using the 2016 state-level results, as well as the results of the rural/urban divide from the 2010 census found [here](https://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/geography/guidance/geo-areas/urban-rural/2010-urban-rural.html), we can create a similar plot to the one in your question, which shows us Vermont and Maine as the two outliers on the left-hand upper quadrant:

| State | Urban Percentage of Population | Trump Votes | Clinton Votes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Maine | 38.66 | 335593 | 357735 |
| Vermont | 38.90 | 95369 | 178573 |

[image]

If we instead use the county-level results from [here](http://www-personal.umich.edu/%7Emejn/election/2016/countyresults.csv), we can go a little deeper. Performing the same analysis shows the expected trend; the more urban a populace, the more likely it is to vote Democrat. It also allows us to find counties which are outliers like Vermont & Maine, which I have defined as an Urban population smaller than 25%, but which voted by a majority of over 50 points for Clinton in 2016. This gives us the following seven counties, showing that you were correct in your prediction of the black belt of AL & MS producing outliers. The remaining three counties all hold Indian reservations, which seems to be the explanation for this voting pattern.

| State | County | Urban Percentage of Population | Trump Votes | Clinton Votes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alabama | Greene | 0.00 | 838 | 4006 |
| Mississippi | Claiborne | 0.00 | 414 | 2523 |
| Mississippi | Holmes | 13.15 | 1151 | 5820 |
| Mississippi | Jefferson | 0.00 | 489 | 3337 |
| South Dakota | Oglala Lakota | 20.02 | 241 | 2504 |
| South Dakota | Todd | 0.00 | 487 | 1505 |
| Wisconsin | Menominee | 0.00 | 269 | 1003 |

[image]

Comment: It is weird that it is rural. But its racial makeup combined with the rurality is even weirder. Every county in this group CDJB put down is either mostly black or holds a Native American reservation. The only pattern that it is consistent with is the location of the state.